# correct mapping of collection used in two types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

i have a question which really hurts me ATM. I searched a lot, but nothing I found worked until now. I have my POCOs like this (simplified):

```
public class Foo            // goes to Fooes table
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // more FOO properties here

    public List<MyImageType> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Bar            // goes to Bares table
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // more BAR properties here

    public List<MyImageType> Images { get; set; }
}

public class MyImageType    // goes to MyImageTypees table
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // more IMAGE properties here
}
```

As you can see, Foo and Bar do not inherit or something. I have not configured anything special on this.

My problem is, by default, EF generates the database containing Foo_Id and Bar_Id columns in MyImageType table, which obviously contain lots of NULL values.

I tried to introduce a new type ImageContainer, and have Foo and Bar subclass it, and hoped I would end up with a table containing the MyImageType columns, one ID column and a discriminator colum containing the type this data belongs to. But it did not work. Am I missing something important? Please let me know if I must make anything clearer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with Foo_Id and Bar_Id containing null values?

Comment: If `Foo` and `Bar` are separate db tables, then there is no other way (in relational db world) than having 2 FKs. If it's not late and you can introduce common base class *and table* for `Foo` and `Bar` using [TPH](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) or [TPT](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt), then it would be possible to have just one FK.

Comment: @Sam for me it's OK, but my workmates are complaining about it.

Comment: @Ivan OK I'll look into it eventually I will ask for an example. Thank you for the moment!

Comment: i still cannot answer due to my rep, sorry. i just wanted to add our solution. a container class containing the images was introduced, holding the actual list of images. then, for each class using the container, a resolver, deriving ValueResolver (class from AutoMapper) was implemented. so we have indeed now a clean data model, avoiding these null-values and extra columns for each type using images. at any interest i can provide complete code samples.